# MySQL, second INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Hi I trying to do query with couple INNER JOIN, Where is my fault?

SELECT job_tbl.id, accounts.username AS starter, accounts.username AS worker, job_tbl.comment, job_tbl.date, job_tbl.status

FROM job_tbl

INNER JOIN accounts ON job_tbl.starter = accounts.id

INNER JOIN accounts ON job_tbl.worker = accounts.id

job_tbl table here :

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| id | starter | worker | comment | date | status |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| 1  |    1    |    3   |   qwe   | date |   10   |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| 2  |    2    |    1   |   qwe   | date |   10   |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
```

accounts table here:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| id |  username  | extension | email |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| 1  |   Julia    |    100    | email |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2  |    Eve     |    101    | email |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| 3  |    Max     |    102    | email |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
```

result I want it to be :

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| id | starter | worker | comment | date | status |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| 1  |  Julia  |   Max  |   qwe   | date |   10   |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
| 2  |   Eve   |  Julia |   qwe   | date |   10   |
+----+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are joining two table without specifying an `ALIAS` on table `accounts` causing ambiguous state.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.username StarterName,
        c.userName WorkerName
FROM    job_tbl a
        INNER JOIN account b
            ON a.starter = b.id
        INNER JOIN account c
            ON a.worker = c.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 3):

You're not specifying which `accounts` table instance to use as starter or worker.
Try this:

```
SELECT job_tbl.id, job_tbl.description, Starter.username AS starter, Worker.username AS worker, job_tbl.comment, job_tbl.date, job_tbl.status
FROM job_tbl
INNER JOIN accounts AS Starter ON job_tbl.starter = Starter.id
INNER JOIN accounts AS Worker ON job_tbl.worker = Worker.id
```